# INL (Integral Non-Linearity) measurement of ADC

Tags: adc

I am working to measure the static INL error of an ADC and have got a few questions. For the sake of simplicity and to keep the questions more focused assume the ADC's measured output codes have precisely been stored in a PC for subsequent linearity analyses.

The questions:

1. To measure the INL (using the best straight line fit method) we have to nullify both the offset and gain error. I know how to remove the offset error but I do not know how the gain error could be nullified.
2. Suppose the ADC is fed on by a low frequency sin wave. The output will also be the same sin wave plus distortion. Now how could you measure the INL given the output sin wave? It has to take the same procedure as described in (1) but it is not obvious what the gain error is here and how it can be removed. Please clarify.

Comment: In this note, you can find 2 definitions of INL. What is often done is the Best Straight line 
 INL which does not need nullifying offset or gain error. It is also often the best choice ... https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/2/283.html

Comment: I have read the document but it doesn't answer the raised questions.

Comment: What I see in Fig. 1b of the document still relies on offset and gain error nullifying. The best straight line passes through the corrected curve.

Comment: It seems to me that the best straight line INL does not need nullifying offset error or gain error. In fact, manufacturer, unless I am wrong, does not implement these two possibilities on the DAC or ADC itself (he do the work by laser trimming ?) . <<< Best straight-line INL - provides information (only ?) - about offset (intercept) and gain (slope) error >>>

Comment: Correction ... Perhaps a VOSADJ (note 2 page 5) on the MAX108 ? And Gain error between REFOUT and REFIN ? No idea for point 2 and 3.